# R plotly Update Title When Using Transform Filter

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I've created a graph that lets you pick which group's data to plot.  I'd like to change the title when you pick the group, but I'm not sure how or if its possible.  I'm having trouble learning which way to structure lists for certain plotly parameters.  Even if I could add custom text to graph would probably work.

```
#Working Example so Far
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
random_y_prim <- rnorm(100, mean = 50)
mydata <- data.frame(x, random_y, random_y_prim, group = rep(letters[1:4], 25))

# Make Group List Button

groupList <- unique(mydata$group)

groupLoop <- list()
for (iter in 1:length(groupList)) {
  groupLoop[[iter]] <- list(method = "restyle",
                       args = list("transforms[0].value", groupList[iter]),
                       label = groupList[iter])
}


# Set up Axis labeling

f <- list(
  family = "Verdana",
  size = 18,
  color = "#7f7f7f"
)

xLab <- list(
  title = "x Axis",
  titlefont = f
)
yLab <- list(
  title = "y Axis",
  titlefont = f
)


fig <- plot_ly(mydata, x = ~x, y = ~random_y
               , type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
               transforms = list(
                 list(
                   type = 'filter',
                   target = ~mydata$group,
                   operation = '=',
                   value = groupList[1]
                 )
               )
)


fig <- fig %>% 
  layout(
  title = "Updating Practice",
  xaxis = xLab,
  yaxis = yLab,
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      type = 'dropdown',xanchor = 'center',
      yanchor = "top",
      active = 1,
      buttons = groupLoop
    )
  )
)

fig
```

Comment: If you want to update data and the layout you need [update buttons](https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/#update-button).

Comment: Yeah, I see that I need to use "update" instead of restyle, but I can't get the filter to work when I use "update" - I don't know if its how I have the list structured or what.